# jquery mobile - too wide on android

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I am trying to do a simple page using jquery mobile to handle the theme and basic interaction.  I'm using the single page boilerplate as a test, EXACTLY the same code as JQM uses on their page, and it looks fine on my android device if I load their page, but about 2x too wide when I load mine.

http://webuyexotics.theautogallery.com/index2.php
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc4/docs/pages/page-template.html

Anyone have a guess? It's driving me crazy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a viewport meta tag to the head

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"

Comment: already in there.

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Single page template</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc3/jquery.mobile-1.0rc3.min.js"></script>
</head> 


exactly the same as JQM's boilerplate html